# Resolving incorrect padding error while b64 decoding?

Tags: python, encryption, encoding, cryptography, base64

**Function description:**
`decodexorbase64(string, key)` takes the output of the previous
  function (xor'd string and base64 encoded key) and returns the
  original string, in b' format

**My code:**

```
def decodexorbase64(code, keyb64):
    keyoriginal = binascii.a2b_base64(key)
    stroriginal = binascii.a2b_base64(string)
    return (stroriginal, keyoriginal)
```

**Issue:**

`print(decodexorbase64(b'\x02\x01\x04\x00\x03\x00Y^\x00', b'a2VybWl0\n'))`
    gives the error:  `binascii.Error: Incorrect padding`

**What can I write in my code to avoid this error?**

Comment: There is literally not a thing I understand about your question. Your parameters don't match the vars in your block and you seem to mix binary and all kinds of encodings semi-randomly.

Answer (score 0):

You should xor binary with binary, not base 64 with base 64 and expect that it returns base 64. If you XOR two ASCII encoding of base 64 then you will likely get many bytes set near zero (as the first bits likely match), which seems to reflect the `code` or `string`in the question.

First decode, if required, then XOR, then encode again if you require text as output.

---

Notes:

- I think you rewrote the names of your parameters in the function declaration;
- the first array (the `code`) seems binary, not base 64
- the second array has a final line terminator, which is not part of the base 64 alphabet